# Como converter dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss para yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Tags: c#, .net-core

Se tento converter a data desta forma no Visual Studio funciona, mas quando faço deploy a API (esta já publicada) responde erro 500.

```
string added = "10/09/2018 10:20:11";
added = DateTime.ParseExact(added, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Será que tem haver com o .net core?

Basta remover que funciona novamente no deploy

Deixa de funcionar assim que publico no Linux Ubuntu usando apache.

Fiquei sem saber o que causa o problema mas resolvi fazendo a conversão manualmente da seguinte forma

```
private string ConverterData(string added)
{
    string datahora = added;
    var splitdatahora = datahora.Split(' ');
    string data = splitdatahora[0];
    string hora = splitdatahora[1];
    var splitdata = data.Split('/');
    var dia = splitdata[0];
    var mes = splitdata[1];
    var ano = splitdata[2];
    string novoFormato = ano + "-" + mes + "-" + dia + " " + hora;
    return novoFormato;
}
```

Comment: O código é exatamente este? Inclusive a parte da `string`? Tem certeza que a `string` não tá vindo de outro lugar? Isso aí tá com cara de falta de cuidado com a cultura...

Comment: De onde vem a variável `added`? Provavelmente o idioma padrão do seu servidor está configurado para inglês e isso altera o formato padrão da data, por isso o erro acontece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema provavelmente é por causa que o `CultureInfo` na máquina onde você fez o deploy é diferente da sua máquina local (que deve ser `pt-br`). Tente colocar o seguinte trecho de código abaixo colocando o `CultureInfo` como `pt-br`. Eu testei aqui e funcionou.

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR", false);
string added = "10/09/2018 10:20:11";
added = DateTime.ParseExact(added, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", culture)
                            .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

Tive um problema parecido corrigi fazendo assim:

```
string added = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: De que forma isso poderia ajudar em algo?